# Weird update of a list of string lists

Tags: python, string, list, updates

I stumbled upon  an intriguing behaviour of a list of string lists
in Python 3.7.3.
I define the lists of lists as below, and  update an element:

```
    s = [['']*2]*2
    s[1][1] =  'why?'
    print(s)
```

It prints:

```
[['', ''], ['', '']]
[['', 'why?'], ['', 'why?']]
```

I cannot figure out why is not updated the right element.
A first thought was to define `s = [['    ']*2]*2`, with 4 spaces = `len('why?')`, as elements, but the wrong update persists.
Redefining the list `s` explicitly, and performing the same update as above, I get the right result:

```
    s = [['', ''], ['', '']]
    s[1][1]= 'why?'
    print(s)
```

```
[['', ''], ['', 'why?']]
```

I'm  working with such lists as lists of  tooltips associated to  large  heatmaps. I can avoid this issue converting the list of n-spaces lists to a `np.array`, but I'd like to know why the above odd update occurs. Thanks!

Comment: See this: [multi-dimensional lists](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list)

Comment: *replicating a list with * doesn’t create copies, it only creates references to the existing objects*

Comment: Also see [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/5431791)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python \* operator, creating list with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306418/python-operator-creating-list-with-default-value)

Comment: Thank you @SayandipDutta ! It's for the first time when I encountered this issue. I didn't know about the details pointed out in your link to docs.

Comment: @xecafe No problem, it happens. Actually, in most of the cases when you come up with a question, chances are the question has already been asked and answered on SO, so I would suggest you to research thoroughly before asking. Try searching with different keywords. Anyway, glad to help!