# Python 2D array is not initialising properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to initialise a 2D array like this (pasting the code extracts only)

```
    ary = [[0]*cols]*rows
```

for insertion, I am doing

```
    def Insert(self, val): 
        ary[0][2] = val
```

After that, I insert value like this:
myS.Insert(15)

When I try to print the array using a loop, it should print the value 15 only at index 0, 2. But it is printing that value against every index e.g. at 1, 2 then 2, 2 then 3, 2 and so on.

```
for r in range(self.rows):
        for c in range(self.cols):
            #print (self.sheet[r][c])
            self.col = c
            print ('value at row index ', r, ' col index ', c , ' is ',  self.sheet[r][c])
```

Output is

```
value at row index  0  col index  0  is  0
value at row index  0  col index  1  is  0
value at row index  0  col index  2  is  15
value at row index  0  col index  3  is  20
value at row index  0  col index  4  is  0
value at row index  1  col index  0  is  0
value at row index  1  col index  1  is  0
value at row index  1  col index  2  is  15
value at row index  1  col index  3  is  20
value at row index  1  col index  4  is  0
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? is it the assignment or the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python \* operator, creating list with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306418/python-operator-creating-list-with-default-value)

Comment: The `*` operator on non-numerics creates *shallow* copies.  That is, all the elements of the result are references to the same object.  Yes, changes to that object (the inner list, in your case) via one of the resulting references will be visible through all the others, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically in python using the * operator on a list of one element creates a list with that element as default.
 But using it on a full list will create copies of the list that point to the same memory address, so when you change a row you're changing all of them since they point to the same list.
 Generate like this instead:

```py
ary = [[0]*cols for j in range(rows)]
```

Using the list comprehensions 'disables' that copying off the memory address and creates actual copies instead.

Comment: Also, `a = [[]]*2 ; a[0].append(1) ; a` outputs `[[1], [1]]`. A good answer should mention the existence of immutable and mutable objects.

Comment: Is it the way to declare the dynamic 2D array (the syntax that you wrote)? And the loop for printing would remain the same?

Comment: I declared it like this but it's printing the same. How can we use the list comprehensions to avoid copying the memory addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You can work it out by using `numpy array`, then simply assigning your value at the right index.

```py
import numpy as np

cols = 3
rows = 5
ary = np.zeros((rows, cols))  # create an array of '0' 

ary[0][2] = 15  # what you are interested in
```

Also be careful of your functions names, since there already exists a native `insert` method for lists !

Cheers.

Comment: `.insert()` is a **method** of lists

Comment: yes my bad, I corrected it

Comment: Defining a _function_ `insert` doesn't interfere with the _list method_ `insert`.

Comment: If you name a function `insert`, you are definitely **NOT** shadowing the `insert` method, so the whole final comment is not particularly relevant.

Comment: If you're curious of my down vote, the OP is struggling with lists, and understanding the difference between a mutable and an immutable object. Hence, in my opinion you suggesting to use Numpy is completely off topic, even misleading.

Comment: Yes, but it is only for the sake of getting rid of any possible confusion.
Edit : I understand

Comment: There is **NO** possible confusion, a function is a function is a function, a method is a method is a method - Gertrude Stein.

Comment: I am getting this
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: If you are using an IDE as pycharm or spyder, type `pip install numpy` in your terminal. And do not forget to `import numpy as np` at the beginning of your code afterwards